# Is it possible to show datatables (including the data) in a generated pdf from knpsnappy?

Tags: symfony, pdf, datatables, knp-snappy

At the moment I am generating a pdf using knpsnappy, i'm showing a bunch of data I already want to show in there, but it'd be really handy to put one of my datatables in there, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would have the data as JSON and then display it with ajax. [Example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/jsonp)

If you don't have a lot of data, then you could just have it in your script file as `let myJsonData = {[...JSON data...]}`